# The workspace is in Gluon format... "run an update to fix it" - how?

Tags: plasticscm

I accidentally opened up Gluon instead of the standard interface. Now, when I go to Pending Changes, there's a banner that says

> New changeset(s) have been detected in the repository, you can update-to/merge-from the latest changeset

with a button labeled `View new changes`. Clicking that button results in the message

> The workspace is in Gluon format and needs to be converted to 'standard'. Just run an update to fix it.

**How exactly would I "just run an update"?**

I would think that I should be clicking the button in the Workspace tab that says `Update workspace`, however this process is interrupted by the same error message.

Comment: A temporary workaround until a proper answer is found is to delete the workspace and re-create it, manually shelving and reapplying any changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting to note that the Gluon and the standard Plastic workspaces have a different structure, so if you if you are using both GUIs, please create two independenet workspaces.

Regarding the error, the workspace currently has a Gluon format so you need to run and update opeartion on it from the regular GUI in order to covert it again to a standard Plastic SCM workspace. For that purpose, you can open the branch explorer, right-click a branch and switch workspace to this branch. This way, the workspace will be converted to "standard" again.

Note that you can only run a switch (or update) operation if you don't have pending to commit changes in the workspace.